# Good Practices For Generating Variations of SQL Queries

Tags: java, oracle

I'm working on a (Java) project that requires different variations of SQL queries depending on the filters the user wants to use.

I have 4+ queries right now that all use the same tables, require the same table joins, and use the same "order by". Currently I have hard coded these queries into the code and I'm not happy with that. I would like to dynamically generate them but I'm having trouble figuring out a solution or if I even should bother to generate them.

Note: I can not use stored procedures.

EXAMPLE:

```
SELECT t1.column1, t2.column2, t3.column3 FROM
     (SELECT column1, column2, sum(column3) FROM t1
          WHERE X = Y
          GROUP BY column1, column2
          ORDER BY column1)
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.column1 = t2.column1
LEFT JOIN t3 on t1.column2 = t3.column2
WHERE Y = Z AND A = B
ORDER BY t1.column1
```

The differences are in the WHERE, SELECT, and GROUP BY statements.  I could put nested if-statements between the dynamic parts but that seems too messy.

```
if ()
    "SELECT A"
else
    "SELECT B"
+ "FROM T1"

if ()
    "WHERE x = y

"LEFT JOIN ..."
etc.
```

Doing something like this feels wrong. Should I just stick to hard coding them or is there a better solution?

EDIT: I included it in the tags but I wanted to note up here that I'm using Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same type of problem on projects I've done.  In some of these cases I've used the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern to create dynamic SQL statements.  One advantage of using a Builder is that you can unit test your Builder for all the combinations of your criteria.  Yes, you will still have some conditional logic, but it will all be encapsulated in your SQL Builder.

Comment: Is there a library for this that you would recommend or should I create my own?

Comment: I've used Hibernates Criteria API and the JPA2 Criteria Builder API.  Those are fine for basic use, but as the queries you want to write get more complex the usefulness of those APIs decline sharply, IMHO.  Using those APIs also assume you have the Entity relationships mapped the way you want to query for the data.  This may not be the case.  Thus, I've always rolled my own SQL Builder for complex querying.  As @Thilo has mentioned, there is JOOQ and Querydsl if you're set on using a library.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than one good solutions for this -  there are several tools for creating typesafe and easly manipulable SQL strings out there in Java.

But since you are using Oracle, the best way to go is probably prepared statements.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: It seems these two suggestions are not exclusive. All data access libraries worth their salt will make use of prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a few (less than, say, ten) combinations, you could have the hard-coded SQL strings to choose from. For more than that, you want to programmatically build the statements on the fly. There is no good way to do this with just JDBC, you might want to invest the time to look at some database access libraries.

To avoid having to manipulate SQL strings when dynamically building database queries, have a look at [jOOQ](http://www.jooq.org/). Or, if you want to go that way, an ORM (such as JPA) will also have a CriteriaBuilder.

You will still have the same conditional statements and logic, but at least you can work on Java objects instead of having to manipulate strings and worry that you get all keywords in the right order and all parens balanced.